# How do I cleanup remote git branches that have already been merged?

Tags: git, bash, grep

I have a few repos that I want to clean up, and they have hundreds of branches that have already been merged to master. This is what I have so far `git branch -r --merged | grep -v master | xargs git push origin --delete` 
The issue I haven't been able to get past is the matched branch list comes back as `origin/branchname` but the git command has to be `git push origin --delete branchname` and I haven't been able to remove the `origin/` part of each line when passing it to xargs. 
So far I've taken this list and used sublime text to get me the last 10% of the way there, but I was wondering how to do the last part without taking out of the terminal, and generating a very long set of individual commands just to put them back in the terminal.

I've tried using `grep -o` and `sed` but neither approach has worked. I'm using the console on a Mac OS X system.

**Example**
I have the following remote branches come back from `git branch -r --merged`

```
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
origin/master
origin/feature/DEV-1122
origin/release/1.0
origin/release/1.1
```

To clean up `release/1.0` branch remotely I need the following command:

```
git push origin --delete release/1.0
```

But the command `git branch -r --merged | grep -v master | xargs git push origin --delete` will generate the following command:

```
git push origin --delete origin/release/1.0
```

I need to be able to strip the `origin/` output from the `git branch -f --merged` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
git branch -r --merged | grep -v master | cut -d'/' -f2 | xargs git push origin --delete
```

To display complete line after the first `/`, use this:

```
git branch -r --merged | grep -v master | cut -d'/' -f2- | xargs git push origin --delete
```

Comment: That's pretty close! I also want to include the rest of the line after the first `/` so if you update your cut command to `cut -d'/' -f2-` I'll mark it as the answer :)

Comment: For scripting you should use plumbing commands (i.e. `for-each-ref` instead of `branch`).  `git for-each-ref --merged |grep -v master |grep refs\/remotes\/origin\/ |cut -d'/' -f4-` is a good starting point

Comment: What's the advantage of using plumbing instead of porcelain in this instance? Is there something in branch that will cause issues in some edge case?

Comment: @rodmunera can you provide a sample of the output you are looking for, for better understanding.